Does drizzle ORM auto rollbacks when there is an exception or do I need to call tx.rollback?
I'm building an API with nestjs and drizzle. When there is an error and I need to early return and respond the Request with an HTTP error, I do:
throw new HttpException('message', code);

and nest will catch it and send the http response. Drizzles documentation do not mention auto rollback and only shows rolling back a transaction by calling tx.rollback().
When I want to rollback a transaction is it enough to throw an HttpException or do I need to first explicitly call tx.rollback() and then throw the exception?

In theory it depends on the DB and driver used.
But in most (if not all) cases the answer should be yes drizzle does auto rollback. It would be quite a bad implementation of transactions if they didn't: it would mean that any thrown error exposes you to the risk of committing half of your transaction.
I did the test on a postgres DB, using pg, and I confirm that any uncaught error will rollback the transaction. So you do not need to call tx.rollback if an error is already being thrown.
Looking a bit at the code of their drivers, it seems that they always implement transactions as just a try..catch (and calling tx.rollback actually simply throws an error)
Some examples:

pg
mysql2
libsql

